# AngularJS: GET parameter via $routeParams remains undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS (v1.3.8) I try to read a GET parameter from a URL which looks like this: http://www.foo.com/whatever1?keyword=bla

Using the following code, keyword for whatever reason remains undefined:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/myangularscript.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">

[...]

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript (myangularscript.js):

```
    myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

    myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope,$http,$routeParams,$location) {
        alert($routeParams.keyword); //undefined
        alert($location.search().keyword); //undefined
    });
```

Added route definition (has to be placed where exactly??):

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            when('/whatever1/:keyword', {
                controller: 'myController'
            });
        }]);
```

Comment: and your route definition is... ? There's always `$location.search().keyword`

Comment: Are you defining the route somewhere?

Comment: I added a route definition, unsure whether it's correct or where to place it exactly.

Comment: `$routeParams` only contains parameters that are defined in your route. AFAIK, `ngRoute` only supports path parameters. You will have to use `$location` as indicated in my first comment or move to `ui-router` which does support query parameters

Comment: Like Phil said, if you want to use your route setup, change the url to http://www.foo.com/whatever1/bla and then your routeparams should give you the right keyword value.

Comment: I'd like to stick to the current format, thus I can't use ngRoute as Phil pointed out. I changed the code and added $location but still can't read keyword.

Comment: It is somewhat painless to switch to ui-router, which will pass those parameters into $stateParams and ui-router gives you much more flexibility as well as features. https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Comment: Seems I'm incorrect about `$routeParams` and `$location.search`. According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams), `$routeParams` should include query parameters. [This Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7KVlbv13VIrq32eapSgs?p=preview) works as expected too

Comment: Based on your template definition of the controller in the body tag, you're not actually using angular routes and I suspect your intention is not to use routes. So $routeParams will not work. You're better off using something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery). If you want to use $routeParams then you will have to change your program to use angular routes. Your url would look like http://www.foo.com/#whatever1?keyword=bla

Comment: As I said, I'd like to stick to the plain URL format (foo.com/whatever1?keyword=bla), not using hashtag notation. Thus, as user2341963 proposed, I decided to grab the entire URL using document.location and manually extracting the parameters employing string operations.